# static variable inside static method doesn't change

Tags: c++, oop, static, static-methods

I want to create a class which has a static method that returns a reference to a static variable(which is declared inside the method). What I want is when calling the method to get the reference of the static variable. Then when I modify it outside the class and call the method again to get the same value I previously set.

Here's what I tried:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A
{
public:
    static int& f()
    {
        static int i;
        return i;
    }
};

int main()
{
    static int i;
    i = A::f();

    cout << i << endl;

    i = 11;
    cout << i << endl;

    i = A::f();
    cout << i << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The problem is that the output of this code is:

```
0
11
0
Press <RETURN> to close this window...
```

Why doesn't it return `0, 11, 11` and how can I make it return `0, 11, 11`?

Note: I want the static variable to be explicitly declared inside the method and not as member.

Thanks!

Comment: You never do `A::f()=something;`

Comment: Why not? Tried and works great...

Comment: "You never do" as in "you forgot to do", not as in "you must not do".

Comment: you mean it's bad practice?....i saw similar code in a very large production application i'm working on, this is why i'm asking.

Comment: No! As I tried to explain in the last message, you are misunderstanding my English. It is a good thing to write `A::f()=3`. The program in your question was bad because it didn't contain any such statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To have the local variable `i` refer to the same variable inside the function, declare it as a reference:

```
static int& i = A::f();
```

Otherwise, you're just creating a new variable and using assigning `A::f()` to it.

Answer (score 6):

This is because you copy the value returned by reference into a regular variable: when you store `int&` in an `int`, it is no longer a reference.

What you should do instead is

```
int &i = A::f();
```

Note that the local `i` needs not be `static`: reference to static data can be stored in automatic variables without a problem.

Answer (score 4):

It needs to be an `int&` in `main`, if you want changes to that `int` to be changes to the int referred to by the return value of `f`.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to initailce your variable. And ***you can use it directly*** or you may want to "conserv" the reference in a local reference.
But you can not reasign these local references. For example:

```
int main()
{
    A::f()=3;
    cout << A::f() << endl;

    static int &i = A::f();
    cout << i << endl;

    i = 11;
    cout << i << endl;

    cout << A::f() << endl;

    int &ii = A::f();
    cout << ii << endl;

    return 0;
}
```